# Svelte components flicker on page refresh

Tags: svelte

No matter what I do, the `Child` component appears for a brief moment, despite the `showComponent` being `false`.

Why is this happening?

I've read that a possible cause might be the fact that all HTML is rendered before the app decides what to do with it, but I don't know how to prevent it.

**Parent Component**

```
<script>

    let entities;
    
    async function getData(workspaceUid) {
        entities = await fetchGet(`/api/workspaces/${workspaceUid}/entities`);
    }
    
    $: fetchEntities($workspaceUid);
    
    $: showComponent = entities.length > 0

</script>
    
<Child bind:showComponent />
```

**Child Component**

```
{#if showComponent}
    content
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to prevent it like this.

```
<script>

    let entities;
    let showComponent;
    
    async function getData(workspaceUid) {
        entities = await fetchGet(`/api/workspaces/${workspaceUid}/entities`);
        showComponent = entities.length > 0
    }
    
    $: fetchEntities($workspaceUid);
    
</script>
    
<Child bind:showComponent />
```